# .NET Core API File Upload Progress

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-storage

There is a Javascript library where you can get the file upload progress. This however only shows the progress of the upload to the api - when the progress reaches 100%, the API method is entered. I am using Azure Storage to store the files uploaded, it takes about the same time for the method to upload the stream to the storage container. Is there a good way to relay progress back? I had a look at SignalR and I don't think this is what im looking for, anyone have any ideas of how to relay this information?

I do use background jobs a lot too and was considering turning the stream to a byte array then sending as a job, this worries me for large files tho.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: Front end is separate to API

Comment: You can find useful pointer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804855/how-to-upload-files-and-see-a-progress-bar

Comment: Nice one thanks but the front end is a separate application so this isn't possible

Comment: I have done a good bit of searching around and decided to go with: Adding a token with the upload call that corresponds to a progress record which is updated by the upload blob event (bytes uploaded). I've then exposed an API call where you are able to provide the token and get the progress at the point of call (this can be polled)

Comment: Turns out im an idiot and have request logging on which outputs the file to log which takes a load of time. Removing this logging on file uploads and the % progress is correct